# HTML buggy in Heroku?

Tags: html, heroku

I made a web application recently and wanted to upload it to Heroku. I use solely Javascript, CSS, and HTML. I loaded it on Heroku.

Whenever I click the links it takes me nowhere. 
In my tests (using the git folder) I tried two of the methods listed [here](http://webapplog.com/deployment-of-static-files-to-heroku/). I've done the `index.php` method and the `config.ru` method.

Nothing seems to work. How can I fix this?

Comment: Could you show a snippet of the non working code? Your question doesn't have information for us to give you an informed answer.

Comment: If I were you, I would go after the Node.js solution from the page you linked to. Older Heroku stacks used a proxying web server in front of your web app but the new default Cedar stack has no web server at all. So, writing one in Node.js seems like the way to go.